How random is the modulus of a large semiprime number?
I was generating swaths of 2048-bit RSA keys for testing and was trying to come up with a compact way to name the files rather than dumping the whole public modulus (>500 chars in hex) into filename. Briefly, RSA keys are two random large primes (p, q, each on the order of 2keylength/2), and the "public modulus" is the semiprime pq (= n).
Say that I represent pq as a base-16 (hexadecimal) number and take the last c characters, aka: $pq \pmod{16^c} = n_{trunc}$. The last digit would obviously always be odd because neither prime is 2 and the semiprime can't be divisible by 2. So if I use the hex-modulus of the public modulus, it would have a maximum of $4^c - 1$ bits of actual randomness.
Is there something else that's further cutting down the randomness, however? If I just truncated a decimal number, would that also be worse (aside from the lower 'bit density', $\log_2{10} \approx 3.32 < \log_2{16} = 4 $ thus losing another $\frac{1}{\log_2{5}} \approx 0.43$ bits?
Exploring corner cases, wondering if this logic implies that in some cases 'less bit-dense' digits (lower bases, e.g. base31 vs base32) could hold more bits of randomness for a given digit length?

Not quite sure what you mean with "how random" here. Apart from the last binary digit , the binary expansion of $n$ seems quite arbitary. Small factors are of course impossible for $n$ , but this gives no useful restrictions for the bits of $n$.

'How random' in this case I'd maybe frame as 'how many possible values are there'? That doesn't quite capture it, as if I come up with a 'truncated form' mapping of integers 1 to $10^6$ to integers 1 to 10 where if the integer in the domain is >10, it's mapped to 10, all the values are possible, but the 'evenness' is obliterated (compared to a mapping where you just do mod 10)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions seems relevant, as does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_bias

You’ve already observed that the semi prime will be odd, and you can use this to shave off one bit. You can do the same trick with the first few primes (I think the first 233 primes) where you store only the possible residues. Then, instead of having $2^{2048}$ possibilities, you’ll have
$$
\left\lceil 2^{2048}/\prod_{p=2}^{1471}p
\right\rceil \prod_{p=2}^{1471} (p-1)=
4\prod_{p=2}^{1471} (p-1)\approx 2^{2044.5}.
$$
But that’s a lot of work for just a few bits. You could work on reusing the fractional bits so you don’t need two whole bits for the remaining part; if you’re lucky you can squeeze this down to 2044 bits, but I’m not sure that’s achievable.
In any case, you’ll have something like $k\choose2$ possibilities, with $k=\pi(2^{1024})-\pi(2^{1023})$
so you’re not going to be able to go below 2026 bits or so in any case.
